# zapier basics AUTH failed while connecting it to my Laravel app (caltweets)

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, zapier

I want to integrate zapier into my laravel app(caltweets) but when I'm adding the information in the zapier and try to test my Authentication. It says we are hitting an error while adding your new account.

[this is the error ]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAPIB.png

[this is the domain that I'm entering ]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urMSm.png

[here I'm testing]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/biGT9.png

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is on your server's side. Zapier is making a request to `'https://abhi.businessscheduler.com//login'`, but your server isn't handling it correctly (and giving a 500 error). Check your logs to see the actual error. You can likely handle the error from Zapier better.